# How to substring BigDecimal

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

I have bigDeciaml format and digits like 14.2345 or 2.567 or 6.65346. How to format bigDeciaml to leave 3 characters after dot?

Comment: You can't. believe it or not, but a BigDecimal is NOT a String. You should be looking at "rounding" your numbers, not substring

Comment: You might want to look at `DecimalFormat` and the JavaDoc on the class. This let's you define a number format which includes rounding/truncation and let's you _format_ a `BigDecimal` to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a formatted display of BigDecimal, which includes conversion to String.

You may use

```
var formatted = String.format("%.3f", myBigDecimal);
```

Comment: after that i have NumberFormatException

Comment: Did you assign a value to this placeholder's example `myBigDecimal`? Can you copy details of NumberFormatException here (no screenshot, please)?